# How to send data/ variable from View to Cotroller on a function MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

im working on a MVC projekt. 
how can i send the variable value from the view to the controller.

this is where i want to get the Id from; a GridviewROw

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('test.aspx?id=" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Id") + "','myprofilewindow','width=400,height=200,toolbar=0,resizable=0');");
```

i want to send it to a controller that contains this function

```
 public ActionResult Delete(Object obj)
    { 

    // TODO
        // Delete the user which its id = obj.id ; 
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: The only data you're passing is an integer id, so your action should accept an integer id. Why in the world would you even try to accept an `Object`?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do this through a route, the query string, or the request body.

From the way it looks, you should just be able to to do this.

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id) ...
```

Comment: i dont understand what u mean with" Usually you do this through a route, the query string, or the request body."

Comment: @LinaFarid thats how mvc binds its data to actions.